# Prevent line break after SOME (sub)section declarations

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to prevent the automatic line break that happens after a (sub)section declaration, but only for some subsections.

I know that I could use:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
```

but this would then apply to all subsections rather than just the ones that I want.

The motivation for this is that I want to define sections that will appear in the table of contents, so I can't use something like \textbf{...} either.

Is this possible to do? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this is to define another command at the subsection level, omitting the code that results in the line break.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to test this at the moment, so this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Should these subsections be numbered?

Comment: No, they so not need to be numbered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Since I overlooked the “unnumbered criterion” at first, I'll provide two implementations. The easiest one is for numbered run-in subsections, let's start with it first.

## Numbered run-in subsections

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\runinsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}%
  {2}% level
  {\z@}% indentation of heading from the left margin
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% absolute value = beforeskip
  {-1.5em \@plus -.1em}% when negative, opposite = skip to leave right of a
                       % run-in heading.
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}% style
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\runinsubsection{A run-in subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\runinsubsection{Other run-in subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Other subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Two pages (assembled screenshots)]

## Unnumbered run-in subsections

These are slightly trickier, as unnumbered sections, subsections, etc. generally don't reach the table of contents. So, we use normal code for unnumbered subsections, except that we patch it temporarily to add the run-in subsection title to the table of contents.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\let\@ssect@ORIG\@ssect
\let\@runin@ssect\@ssect

\apptocmd{\@runin@ssect}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
    % Comment out the following line to remove “phantom number” indentation in
    % the TOC
    \protect\numberline{}% no number in TOC
    #5% the title
  }%
  \let\@ssect\@ssect@ORIG       % restore the normal \@ssect
}{}{\FAILED}

\newcommand*{\runinsubsection}{%
  \let\@ssect\@runin@ssect
  \@startsection{subsection}%
  {2}% level
  {\z@}% indentation of heading from the left margin
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% absolute value = beforeskip
  {-1.5em \@plus -.1em}% when negative, opposite = skip to leave right of a
                       % run-in heading.
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}% style
  *% we want an unnumbered subsection
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\runinsubsection{A run-in subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\runinsubsection{Other run-in subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Other subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Two pages (assembled screenshots)]

Comment: I ended up finding a different way to do it: I defined \theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition} and then manually added to the table of contents with \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Definition (...)}. But the above solution works better since I don't need to manually add to the TOC every time.